# Show errors from Controller to a Boostrap Alert

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to add an error message to show errors. Currently I have this in my Controller to handle errors:

```
public partial class SongsManagementController : BaseController
{

    private const string NoDataFound = "No data found.";
    private const string InvalidDataPosted = "Invalid data posted";
    private const string InvalidRequest = "Invalid request.";
    private const string VerificationFailedUnexpectedError = "The following song failed to verify due to an unexpected error, please contact RightsApp support.";
    private const string ConcurrencyError = "The following song failed to verify as another user has since changed its details.";

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("VerifyNewSongs")]
    [AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyNewSongs(List<VerifySongViewModel> verifySongViewModels)
    {
        // Not AJAX method - refuse
        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return RedirectToAction("NewSongs", "SongsManagement");

        if (verifySongViewModels.NullOrEmpty())
        {
            // return error;
            return Json(new JsonBaseModel
            {
                success = false,
                message = InvalidRequest,
                data = null,
                errors = new List<string>
                {
                    InvalidDataPosted
                }
            });
        }
        foreach (var verifySong in verifySongViewModels)
        {
            if (verifySong.WorkId == default(Guid) || verifySong.RowVersion == default(Guid))
            {
                return Json(new JsonBaseModel
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = InvalidDataPosted,
                    data = null,
                    errors = new List<string>
                    {
                        $"Invalid data posted for following song.",
                        $"Song Title: {verifySong.SongTitle}",
                        $"Song Id: {verifySong.UniqueCode}"
                    }
                });
            }
            var work = await _artistAccountService.GetWorkGraphAsync(verifySong.WorkId, includeWriterAmendments: true);
            if (work == default(WorkGraphModels.Work))
            {
                return Json(new JsonBaseModel
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = NoDataFound,
                    data = null,
                    errors = new List<string>
                    {
                        $"No data found for following song.",
                        $"Song Title: {verifySong.SongTitle}",
                        $"Song Id: {verifySong.UniqueCode}"
                    }
                });
            }
            if (work.VerifiedState != Domain.Enumerators.VerifiedStateType.NotVerified)
            {
                return Json(new JsonBaseModel
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = NoDataFound,
                    data = null,
                    errors = new List<string>
                    {
                        $"Song already verified.",
                        $"Song Title: {verifySong.SongTitle}",
                        $"Song Id: {verifySong.UniqueCode}"
                    }
                });
            }
            work.RowVersion = verifySong.RowVersion;
            var workAndAmendment = new WorkGraphModels.WorkAndAmendment
            {
                Original = work,
                Amendment = null
            };
            var verifiedState = await _artistAccountService.VerifyWorkGraphAsync(workAndAmendment, GetLoggedUserId());
            if (!verifiedState.ValidationErrors.NullOrEmpty())
            {
                return Json(new JsonBaseModel
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = NoDataFound,
                    data = null,
                    errors = new List<string>
                        {
                            VerificationFailedUnexpectedError,
                            $"Song Title: {verifySong.SongTitle}",
                            $"Song Id: {verifySong.UniqueCode}"
                        }
                });
            }
            else if (!verifiedState.DatabaseErrors.NullOrEmpty())
            {
                if (!verifiedState.FatalException)
                {
                    // concurrency exception                        
                    return Json(new JsonBaseModel
                    {
                        success = false,
                        message = NoDataFound,
                        data = null,
                        errors = new List<string>
                        {
                            ConcurrencyError,
                            $"Song Title: {verifySong.SongTitle}",
                            $"Song Id: {verifySong.UniqueCode}"
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // fatal
                    return Json(new JsonBaseModel
                    {
                        success = false,
                        data = null,
                        errors = new List<string>
                        {
                            VerificationFailedUnexpectedError,
                            $"Song Title: {verifySong.SongTitle}",
                            $"Song Id: {verifySong.UniqueCode}"
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return Json(new JsonBaseModel
        {
            success = true,
            message = "All songs verified successfully."
        });
    }
};
```

}

This is my Main View:

```
Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_SentricLayout.cshtml";
    var actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();

    @* calc full account code *@
    var fullAccountCode = Model.WorkUniqueCode;
    ViewBag.Title = "New Songs";
}

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajaxval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker")
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    @* DOM ready? *@
    $(function () {
        addTableStylingScripts();
        var selectFormDiv = $('.catalogSelector');
        selectFormDiv.hide();

        $(".records-selected").hide();

        // clear all filter boxes and reset search.
        $("#btnClear").click(function()
        {
            $("#newSongsSearch").find(':input').each(function ()
            {
                if (this.type === "text")
                {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            });

            $("#btnSearch").click();
        });

        @* edit catalogue button *@
        $('#changeCat').click(function () {
            $('#errorContainer').hide();

            var label = $('#catLabel');

            if (label.is(":visible")) {
                label.hide();
                selectFormDiv.show();

                $('#changeCat').addClass("active");
            } else {
                label.show();
                selectFormDiv.hide();

                $('#changeCat').removeClass("active");
            }
        });

        @* edit dropdown *@
        $("#catalogueSelect").on("change", function () {
            @* change display on select change *@
            $('#errorContainer').hide();
            $('#catLabel').show();
            selectFormDiv.hide();
            $('#changeCat').removeClass("active");

            @* set up ajax post to controller *@
            var model = {
                AccountCode: '@fullAccountCode',
                CurrentAccountId: $('#currentAccountId').val(),
                CurrentRowVersion: $('#currentRowVersion').val(),
                NewCatalogueId: $('#catalogueSelect option:selected').val(),
                Action: '@actionName'
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangeCatalogue", "ArtistAccount")',
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                    @* ajax worked *@
                    if (result.ChangeStatus === "Success")
                    {
                        var newSelected = $('#catalogueSelect option:selected').text();
                        $('#catLabel').html(newSelected);

                        @* update dropdown context *@
                        var newSelectedId = $('#catalogueSelect option:selected').val();
                        $('#currentCatalogue').val(newSelectedId);

                        @* update rowversion *@
                        var newRowVersion = result.OldOrNewRowVersion;
                        $('#currentRowVersion').val(newRowVersion);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#errorContainer').show();
                        $('#errorMessage').html(result.ErrorMessage);

                        @* return downdown context *@
                        var currentCatId = $('#currentCatalogue').val();
                        $("#catalogueSelect").val(currentCatId);
                        $('#catalogueSelect').select2({ width: '180px', dropdownAutoWidth: true });
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    @* failed *@
                    $('#errorContainer').show();
                    $('#errorMessage').html('There was a server error, please contact the support desk on (+44) 0207 099 5991.');

                    @* return downdown context *@
                    var currentCatId = $('#currentCatalogue').val();
                    $("#catalogueSelect").val(currentCatId);
                    $('#catalogueSelect').select2({ width: '180px', dropdownAutoWidth: true });
                }
            });
        });

        function loadPartialPage(url) {
            $('.spinnerOverlay').removeClass('hide');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.spinnerOverlay').addClass('hide');
                    $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                    addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                }
            });
        }
        function getSelectedWorks() {
            var selectedWorks = $(".individual:checked");
            var works = [];
            $.each(selectedWorks, function (key, value) {
                works.push(getSelectedWork(this));
            });
            return works;
        }

        // verify songs in bulk
        $(document).on("click", ".js-verify-songs", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var works = getSelectedWorks();
            verifySongs(works);
        });
        // reject songs in bulk
        $(document).on("click", ".js-reject-songs", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var works = getSelectedWorks();

        });

        function getSelectedWork(element) {
            var work = new Object();
            work.WorkId = getRowData(element, "id");
            work.RowVersion = getRowData(element, "rowversion");
            work.UniqueCode = getRowData(element, "uniqueworkid");
            work.SongTitle = getRowData(element, "songtitle");
            return work;
        }

        // verify one song
        $(document).on("click", ".js-verify-song", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var works = [];
            works.push(getSelectedWork(this));
            verifySongs(works);
        });
        // reject one song
        $(document).on("click", ".js-reject-song", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var works = [];
            works.push(getSelectedWork(this));
        });

        function verifySongs(songs) {
            $('.spinnerOverlay').removeClass('hide');
               $.ajax({
                   url: '@Url.Action("VerifyNewSongs", "SongsManagement")',
                   data: JSON.stringify(songs),
                   type: 'POST',
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   success: function (result) {
                       $('.spinnerOverlay').addClass('hide');
                       if (result.success) {
                           loadPartialPage($(".paginate_button.active a").attr("href"));
                       }
                   },
                   error: function(error) {
                       $('.spinnerOverlay').addClass('hide');
                   }
               });
        }

        @* Pagination Async Partial Handling *@
        $(document).on("click",
            "#indexPager a",
            function() {
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass('disabled') || $(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
                    return false;
                loadPartialPage($(this).attr("href"));

                return false;
            });



        $(document).on("change",
            "#pageSizeSelector",
            function() {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                loadPartialPage(selectedValue);
                return false;
            });

        @* Sorting Async Partial Handling *@
        $(document).on("click",
            "#tableHeader a",
            function()
            {
                loadPartialPage($(this).attr("href"));
                return false;
            });
        });

        // Ensure that after paging and sorting ajax calls we re-bind
        // the change event and hide the record count label.
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $(".records-selected").hide();
            $(".individual").on("change", determineActionButtonAvailability);
            $(".selectall").click(function () {
                $(".individual").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
                determineActionButtonAvailability();
            });
        });

        // Search functions
        $('.searchDivider').click(function (e) {
            $('#searchFields').slideToggle();
            var isSearchShown = $(this).find('.caret').hasClass("caret-up");
            if (isSearchShown) {
                $(this).children('span').replaceWith('<span class="bg-white">Search <b class="caret"></b></span>');
            } else {
                $(this).children('span')
                    .replaceWith('<span class="bg-white">Search <b class="caret caret-up"></b></span>');
            }
        });

        $(".searchArea input:text").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#btnSearch").click();
            }
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {
                $('#searchFields').show();
            }
        });

        $(".searchArea input:text").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#btnSearch").click();
            }
        });


        // Checks individual checkboxes and displays the count
        $(".individual").on("change", determineActionButtonAvailability);

        $(".selectall").click(function () {
            $(".individual").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
            determineActionButtonAvailability();
        });

        //Disable Top Verify Button if two or more checkboxes are selected.
        $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        //Disable Action Button in the columns when more than one checkbox is selected
        $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        $(".individual").on("click", function () {
            if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
                $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', true);
                $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });

        // When one or more works are selected, will enable the top action menu.
        // Will disable when none selected.
        function determineActionButtonAvailability() {
            if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
                $(".records-selected").show();
                $("#selected").text($(".individual:checked").length);
                $("#total").text($(".individual").length);


                $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', false);
                if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
                }
            }
            else {
                $(".records-selected").hide();
                $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
                $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }

        // Enforce only numeric input in the Unique Id search textbox.
        $(document).on("keydown", ".uniqueCodefield", function (e) {
            var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            var currentVal = $('.uniqueCodefield').val();
            if (key === 8 || key === 9 || key === 13 || key === 37 || key === 39 || key === 35 || key === 36 || key === 46) {
                return true;
            } else if (key === 13) {
                $('#newSongsSearch').validate();
                if ($('#newSongsSearch').valid()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
                }
            else if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && (key < 93 || key > 105)) {
                return false;
            } else if (currentVal.length >= 10) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });

        @* Wire up the Search button click to perform an AJAXified search *@
        $(document).on("click", "#btnSearch", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Only perform the search if the search criteria is valid.
            if (!$('#newSongsSearch').valid()) {
                return false;
            }

            $('.spinnerOverlay').removeClass('hide');

            var model = {
                SearchModel: {
                    WorkUniqueCode: $('#SongCode').val(),
                    SongTitle: $('#SongTitle').val(),
                    CatalogueUniqueCode: $('#CatalogueCode').val(),
                    CatalogueName: $('#CatalogueName').val(),
                    AccountUniqueCode: $('#AccountCode').val(),
                    AccountName: $('#AccountName').val()
                }
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchNewSongs", "SongsManagement")',
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                    addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                }
            });

            return false;
        });




         @* Wire up the Search button click to perform an AJAXified search *@
           $(document).on("click", "#btnSearch", function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $('.spinnerOverlay').removeClass('hide');

               var model = {
                   SearchModel : {
                       Name: $('#ContractNameSearch').val(),
                       ContractType: $('#ContractTypeSearch').val(),
                       CreatedBy: $('#CreatedBySearch').val(),
                       DateFrom : $('#DateFromSearch').val(),
                       DateTo : $('#DateToSearch').val()
                   }
               };
               $.ajax({
                   url: '@Url.Action("SearchContracts", "ClientSetup")',
                   data: JSON.stringify(model),
                   type: 'POST',
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   success: function (result) {
                       $('#tableContainer').html(result);
                       addBootstrapTooltips("#tableContainer");
                   }
               });

               return false;
        });
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/searchusers-autosuggest")
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2"></script>
}


@section additionalStyles {
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/datatables/media/css/cssDatatables")
}

<article class="row">
    <h1 class="pageTitle artistHeader fw200 mb20 mt10">@ViewBag.Title</h1>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-visible">
            @Html.Partial("_NewSongsSearch", Model)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-visible" id="tableContainer">
            @Html.Partial("_NewSongsList", Model)
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Basically where the spinner is, if there is an error, then an alert or modal should display with the type of error, that is in the controller. I am just unsure of how I can get the errors to show in a modal.

Is there any code that is missing from my view that would simplify adding the errors to a modal?

Comment: What is your front end in

Comment: Sorry I will add that now.

Comment: How are you handling the ajax response now?  It seems straightforward to extend that to iterate through the errors list either creating a simple string or a `ul`.  Which bit are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @freedomn-m I am having difficulty with getting a modal to show with errros

Comment: @freedomn-m please see my main view: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qSlFNA

Comment: It's the same as the modal you looked at on their site, instead of triggering it via a button, just trigger it in `errors`

Comment: @TJWolschon how do you mean sorry?

Comment: @Rob check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp), it has some good resources on modals and how to trigger them in javascript. Instead of on button click, you'd just open the modal inside the `error` section of your ajax. I'll try and make an example to show you.

Comment: @TJWolschon Thank you.

Comment: @Rob I'm sorry, I completely misunderstood what you were trying to do. I thought you wanted to handle exceptions raised serverside during an ajax call.

Comment: @TJWolschon I have updated my code, with my main view, basically, I just need an alert to show on an error and display the error message and results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171615/discussion-between-tj-wolschon-and-rob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so with all the information you've given us now, I feel confident with this answer. I created a basic page that just has a button with `id="click"`, that triggers an ajax call to this controller method, similar to yours.

```
public ActionResult VerifyNewSongs()
{
    return Json(new JsonBaseModel
    {
        success = false,
        message = "oops",
        data = null,
        errors = new List<string>
        {
            $"Song already verified.",
            $"Song Title: title",
            $"Song Id: id"
        }
    });
}
```

Now this is considered a successful ajax call, just like yours so when we get sent back to the view, it will end up there. I've edited your ajax call's success section with the code to popup an alert from SweetAlert2 (as per our chat). When you pass back `success = false` from the controller, it will loop through your error list and make a string to pass to the alert.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("VerifyNewSongs")',
    data: JSON.stringify(songs),
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('.spinnerOverlay').addClass('hide');
        if (result.success) {
            loadPartialPage($(".paginate_button.active a").attr("href"));
        }
        else{//MAIN CHANGE STARTS HERE
            var errorString = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.errors.length; i++) {
                errorString += result.errors[i] + "\n";
            }
            swal("Error!", errorString);
        }//MAIN CHANGE ENDS HERE
    },
    error: function (error) {
        $('.spinnerOverlay').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

The main difference between this and your original ajax function is in the else statement when `result.success == false`. If you need any more explanations for anything, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The way i have handled this in the past is to write a bit of an error catch in the controller that puts them into the ViewBag as a list of errors. then on the main view page have some javascript that checks it for content when the page refreshes. I used Toastr instead of a bootstrap popup to display the errors but i'm sure the popup can be used also.

This may be overkill but you could look into [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). It gives live updates to your webpage from your backend.

And thirdly do some fancy things with ajax to ping for errors.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to add this html:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<strong>Danger!</strong> <p id='errorMessage'>This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.</p>
</div>
```

Afterwards you can get your id with following code and insert your error message.

```
document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Put here your error variable";
```

Comment: How would I get the error from the controller and pass it through to the error message?

Comment: If I'm seeing this correct you could just paste the last part 'document.get.....' into the part where you catch your error and after the '=' you put your error that you fetch.

Comment: unfortunately no, I do not have the time at the moment to create a fully working jsfiddle in your way at the moment. I have never worked with JsonBaseModels and don't have the time to look up more about it. All I can say is that where you receive your error message now, you just need to copy the last piece of code and instead of the hard coded text put the error message in place. If you can't find this, I would hardly suggest going with the try catch answer. Try catch may seem hard in the beginning but it is worth putting some time in understanding and using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like wrap the business logic code in your controller in a try catch and then ToString() the exception and pass that back.

```
try
{
    //business logic

    //specific exception
    if (verifySongViewModels.NullOrEmpty())
    {
       throw new InvalidDataException();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // return error;
    return Json(new JsonBaseModel
    {
       success = false,
       message = InvalidRequest,
       data = null,
       error = ex.ToString()
    }
}
```

Then in your view, if the above view model you pass back has any errors trigger model.

Comment: That looks complicated, is there a way I can just pass the errors into a pop up without changing anything?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
return Json(new { error = your error, result = your result });
```

Comment: Thanks I have added my full controller